# Click button programmatically and show pressed animation

Tags: c#, wpf

WPF/.NET4
I have Button1. it has MouseOver and Pressed Animations. i want to click the button with a key on keyboard. i have tried Automation like:

```
ButtonAutomationPeer peer= new ButtonAutomationPeer(Button1);
IInvokeProvider invokeProv = peer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke) as IInvokeProvider;
invokeProv.Invoke();
```

this raises the Button1 click event handler. i have tried this too:

```
Button1.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ButtonBase.ClickEvent));
```

these two work fine but none of these show the pressed state of button. they raise event handler and run the inside code of the button but don't show the reaction of the button when it is clicked. Pressed state is not shown. how should i do this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the [VisualStateManager.GoToState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager.gotostate%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method before raising the event.

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(Button1, "Pressed", true);
Button1.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ButtonBase.ClickEvent));
```

The problem with this is that animations run asynchronously so any lines of code after the event is raised will execute immediately. One way around it would be to get hold of the `Storyboard` that is called when `GoToState` is called.

To do this, you can use `GetVisualStateGroups`

```
var vsGroups = VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(Button1, 0) as FrameworkElement);
VisualStateGroup vsg = vsGroups[0] as VisualStateGroup;

if (vsg!= null)
{
    //1 may need to change based on the number of states you have
    //in this example, 1 represents the "Pressed" state
    var vState = vsg.States[1] as VisualState;
    vState.Storyboard.Completed += (s,e)
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(Button1, "Normal", true);

                //Now that the animation is complete, raise the Button1 event
                Button1.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ButtonBase.ClickEvent));
            };
}

//Animate the "Pressed" visual state
VisualStateManager.GoToState(Button1, "Pressed", true);
```

You may want to store the `Storyboard` (which is in `vState.Storyboard` so that you don't have to perform the search each time but this should let you know when the animation is complete and you can then carry on with the rest of the code (in this case we raise the `Button1` event).

Comment: thanks, works great. just can u tell that how can i set it back to normal state? actually i need that button pressed and after say 10ms back to normal. i tried: VisualStateManager.GoToState(Button1, "Normal", true); but this changes at once so the button always show normal state, i even added thread sleep before Normal state but it isnt shown

Comment: I've updated my answer. It shows how to get the `Storyboard` of the `Pressed` animation which you can then use to detect when the animation is complete by attaching your event handler to the `Complete` event. In this event handler you can raise the `Button1` event.

Comment: thanks a lot but the Completed event is not firing, just like the first solution it presses the button but never returns to Normal state

Comment: What's the value of your `vState`?